# Regular expression to delete repeated words or phrases NO separated by commas or periods

Tags: regex, text, replace, repeat

****Regular expression to delete repeated words or phrases, NO commas in between

Hi!

Trying to clean up some long subtitle files which have some duplicated words and phrases. I was given here a good solution to help with repeated words or phrases **separated by commas**, but I discovered more similar duplications which are **NOT separated by commas**.

I had to use lines to show my examples, because this is ruining all the format!

Below, the examples I need to fix, **words and phrases not separated by commas**:

---

John, I'll take care of my son's

I'll take care of my son's education.

---

And weren't you supposed

supposed to be in Paris?

---

Oh, dear, why are you going to

deny it? to deny it? We all know.

---

Wait a minute. How are we going how are

we going to use this?

---

Sure, that looks like a microwave oven

a microwave oven, a pressure cooker.

---

Well, for example, the boys team

is a very weak team. a very weak team.

---

And the same here, where some extra dash was added to a normal dialog (two dashes in one line instead of only one dash per line):

---

-No? -What about the kid?

-No, I have my toys.

---

How should I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably overthinking/overcomplicating this, but using Notepad++, try:

```
(?i)\b(.*?)([,.?!])(?:\h\1\2)*\h\1([,.?!])(?:\h\1(?=\h))?
```

Replace by `\1\3`. See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDKLum/1)

---

- `(?i)` - Match remainder case-insensitive.
- `\b` - A word-boundary.
- `(.*?)` - A 1st capture group with a lazy matching pattern of any character but newline upto;
- `([,.?!])` - A 2nd capture group holding any of the 4 delimiters you mentioned.
- `(?:` - Open a non-capture group:

  - `\h\1\2` - Match an horizontal space-character and exactly what is matched in the 1st and 2nd capture group.
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group, match it 0+ times.
- `\h\1` - Match another horizontal whitespace and what was captured in the 1st group.
- `([,.?!])` - A 3rd capture group with our final delimiter.
- `(?:` - Open a 2nd non-capture group:

  - `\h\1(?=\h)` - An horizontal whitespace, a backreference to our 1st capture group and a positive lookahead for another whitespace.
  - `)?` - Close 2nd non-capture group and make it optional.

---

In Notepad++:

[image]

---

I feel that someone can/will come up with something much cleaner =)

Comment: OK, JvdV, now I found new problems:

Answer (score 0):

You can search for `\b(.+?\b)(?=[, ])(\1+)` and replace with blank.

**Before replacement**

[image: before]

**After replacement**

[image: after]

Comment: Good but the last line was remained as it is, try to capture last line as well, thanks